# How can I make Spring Data+EclipseLink generate correct SQL Server syntax?

Tags: sql-server, spring, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I am using a Spring Data JPA (v 1.6.0.RELEASE) and EclipseLink (v 2.5.2-M1) to access a SQL Server database (Microsoft JDBC v 4). My repository interface declares this method:

```
List<InboxItemDto> findByOwnerIgnoreCaseAndPatientsStatusIn(String owner, PatientDemographicsStatus[] statuses)
```

When called with a single value in the statuses[] array, it works correctly, but with two values it fails with

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ','
```

The log shows the following trace:

```
SELECT t1.ID, 
    t1.CREATED_TIMESTAMP, 
    t1.FILENAME, 
    t1.OWNER 
FROM UPLOADED_DOCUMENTS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PATIENT_SUMMARIES t0 ON (t0.UPLOADED_DOCUMENTS_ID = t1.ID) 
WHERE ((UPPER(t1.OWNER) = UPPER(?)) 
AND (t0.STATUS IN ((?,?)))) 
ORDER BY t1.CREATED_TIMESTAMP DESC
    bind => [clerk2, NEW, MODIFIED]
```

The fact that it works with a single status, but not with more, seems to imply that the MS JDBC driver won't bind multiple values to the *IN (?,?)*. Does anyone know of a way to make the driver behave in a more standard-compliant way, or alternatively to make Spring/EclipseLink work around the problem?

Edit: I've just tried using Hibernate instead of EclipseLink. It works OK and the SQL in the log looks like this. It appears that the problem lies in the way the statement is prepared or the parameters are bound, rather than the SQL syntax.

```
select
    inboxitemd0_.ID as ID1_7_,
    inboxitemd0_.CREATED_TIMESTAMP as CREATED_2_7_,
    inboxitemd0_.FILENAME as FILENAME3_7_,
    inboxitemd0_.OWNER as OWNER4_7_ 
from
    UPLOADED_DOCUMENTS inboxitemd0_ 
left outer join
    PATIENT_SUMMARIES patients1_ 
        on inboxitemd0_.ID=patients1_.UPLOADED_DOCUMENTS_ID 
where
    upper(inboxitemd0_.OWNER)=upper(?) 
    and (
        patients1_.STATUS in (
            ? , ?
        )
    ) 
order by
    inboxitemd0_.CREATED_TIMESTAMP desc
```

Comment: It's a known bug in Eclispelink - see 

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349477

Comment: Thanks, PaulNUK.  I see it's quite a longstanding bug (2011) too.